# Correct Way to use an async Library with ASP.NET/MVC/REST

Tags: c#, asp.net, asynchronous, async-await, audio-fingerprinting

I have an async Library for audio file processing. Furthermore I want to offer these Methods via Rest. So I made an MVC WebApi Project. The library needs some time to start, so I added a class that offers a way to init and exposes the libraries main object.

```
public static class MusicHandler
{
    public static MusicCapture.MusicCapture MusicCapture;
    public static void init()
    {
        MusicCapture = new MusicCapture.MusicCapture("D:\\Temp", "D:\\test", "E:\\FingerPrintDB2.ss");
        MusicCapture.Start();
    }
}
```

I start it in Application_Start()

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    MusicHandler.init();
}
```

Now when my init method contains some async calls like this:

```
var hashedFingerprints = command.Hash().Result;
```

The programm will just skip over these lines. They do not get executed for all I can tell.
Same thing happens when I call any of the objects async methods from my REST endpoints. When I run the library not from ASP.NET/MVC the code works flawlessly.

I found some comments that said that this is a problem because of deadlocks, but no advice or code how to avoid this/make this work.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Never use '.Result' you should 'await command.Hash()'

Comment: @IeuanW but then I have to make this method async, all the way to the top, but Application_Start() isn't async.

Comment: if you use DI you wouldn't need to add anything to the startup. i.e. if you use a singleton then the entire class would be ready and waiting for other callers to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured my Problem out, it was twofold.

1. My library failing on start was a bug in the library that led to an exception which wasn't bubble up. I was able to mitigate this bug. Async calls on startup with a MVC App with `.Result` inside seem to actually be no problem.
2. My REST calls failing on async could be fixed by changing the rest controllers methods to async. I never would have thought thats possible but I found an example here: https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html

```
// GET api/music
public async System.Threading.Tasks.Task<string> GetAsync()
{
    string result = await MusicHandler.MusicCapture.DetectAsync(5);
    Console.WriteLine("Server returning: " + result);
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

So, if I understand, you want to start something called a `MusicHandler`, which takes a little while to start up.
Once that has loaded, communication with your system will be via RESTful HTTP calls.

In your MusicHandler you can have a flag to state whether it has finished loading.

```
public static class MusicHandler
{
    public static MusicCapture.MusicCapture MusicCapture;
    public static bool Initialized {get;} = False;
    public static void init()
    {
        MusicCapture = new MusicCapture.MusicCapture("D:\\Temp", "D:\\test", "E:\\FingerPrintDB2.ss");
        MusicCapture.Start();
        Initialized = true;
    }
}
```

Then in your MVC Controller, you can examine this flag and return an error if initialization has not completed.

This way you don't need to worry about being `async` all the way to the top.

But I'm surprised you're using `application_start` at all... host this using kestrel and do this setup in `program.cs` or something, where you can be async to the top natively.